# How to implement scroll like that?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, scroll, touch

I want to implement the effect of Scroll a ball on the screen, as the following scenario:

when I touch the screen and move, The ball will scroll, and when I end the touch, the ball will not scroll The ball, keep the same position all time, but it has the scroll effect.

anybody can give me some suggestion? thank you advance.

Comment: I don't really know what you mean?! But have a look at this document: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html Look at this: Responding to Touch Events

Answer (score 1):

It would seem to me that one could use OpenGL ES to draw a sphere, apply a nice texture map to the sphere, and then rotate the sphere based upon what the user was doing.